# How can I store/copy a single user input in multiple variables in Golang?

Tags: go

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "bufio"
      )
  var counter int = 0  
    func main() {

        var (
            read1 *bufio.Scanner;
        )

        read1 = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin);
        read2 := read1
        count_lines(read1)
        read2.Scan()
        fmt.Println("read2: ", read2.Text())
        os.Exit(0);
    }
    
    func count_lines(read *bufio.Scanner){
       read.Scan();
       fmt.Println("read1: ", read.Text())
       if read.Text() == ""{
         return;
       }
       counter++;
       count_lines(read);
    }
```

So, I'm trying to count lines of my user input using recursion. And I also want to work on the same input in a different function. But when I use Scan(), it parses through the input line by line once. The read2 variable is empty. Is there a way to properly copy the user input?
I'm sorry if I couldn't explain properly. I'm new to Go and I don't understand any of it. I've attached an image for reference.
[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAIuu.jpg)
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, and Go!

I'll try to explain the situation in a hopefully understandable and not necessarily technically accurate way.
So, in order to read input from the keyboard you're using a 'scanner' that you 'named' `read1`:

```
read1 = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
```

Then you 'copied' that 'scanner' and named it `read2`

```
read2 := read1
```

So now when you call `count_lines` with the `read1` scanner you count the lines until an empty line is entered.
And, then, you assumed that when you're done with the line counting, `read2` will be able to read the same lines again. But this isn't how it works.

What actually happens is better illustrated with the following. Imagine `read1` and `read2` are two pickaxes ⛏️ that you can use to dig something out of the ground.
So you take a pickaxe you kindly named `read1` and hit a ground (this is equal to `read.Scan()`). Then you pick up the piece you got and check what is inside (`read.Text()`). You, then, repeat the process until you're done pickaxing or until - `read.Text() == ""`.

When you're done, you take the ⛏️ named `read2` and... You cannot pickaxe the same thing again, right? And that is basically how the scanner works.

So to deal with it you can say to yourself, I don't need two pickaxes, one is enough but whatever I excavated from the ground I want to keep and analyze it first for diamonds (count_lines) and then in the second pass for gold (or whatever you like).

So your code might look like:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "bufio"
)
var counter int = 0
var myLines = ""
func main() {

  var (
    read1 *bufio.Scanner;
  )

  read1 = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin);
  count_lines(read1)
  fmt.Println("read2: ");
  fmt.Println(myLines)
  os.Exit(0);
}

func count_lines(read *bufio.Scanner) {
  read.Scan();
  line := read.Text();
  myLines += line + "\n";
  fmt.Println("read1: ", line)
  if read.Text() == ""{
    return;
  }
  counter++;
  count_lines(read);
}
```

*Note*: This is not the idiomatic (recommended) way of doing things. I aimed at changing as little of the original code as possible.